# Proof of Caratheodory Extension theorem

Tags: measure-theory

I was trying to prove that $\mu^*$ is an outer measure. I was easily able to solve the first two conditions of an outer measure(That $\mu^*\ge0 $, and the monotonicity condition) however I have been stuck on the third condition. Specifically can you tell me how to prove that it satisfies the countable subadditivity property:

$$\mu^{*}(\bigcup_{n=1}A_{n})\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu^{*}(A_n) \tag{$\forall   \ \{A_n\}_{n\ge1} \subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$}$$

$\mu^{*}(A)$ is defined as follows:

$$\mu^{*}(A)\equiv \mathrm{inf}\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n):\{A_n\}_{n\ge1} \subset \mathcal{C}, A \subset \bigcup_{n=1}A_{n}\}$$

Here $\mu$ is a measure. $\mathcal{C}\subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is a semialgebra. $\Omega$ is non-empty

The question has been borrowed from Athreya and Lahiri, Measure Theory, Springer.

EDIT: In case you downvote this question, please let me know the reason in the comments below!.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$.  By definition of $\mu^*$, for each $n$ we may find a sequence $B_{n,k} \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $A_n \subset \bigcup_k B_{n,k}$ and $\sum_k \mu(B_{n,k}) \le \mu^*(A_n) + 2^{-n} \epsilon$.

Now $A \subset \bigcup_{n,k} B_{n,k}$ and $$\sum_{n} \sum_k \mu(B_{n,k}) \le \sum_n (\mu^*(A_n) + \epsilon 2^{-n}) = \epsilon + \sum_n \mu^*(A_n).$$
Hence $\mu^*(A) \le \epsilon + \sum_n \mu^*(A_n)$.  Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary we must have $\mu^*(A) \le \sum_n \mu^*(A_n)$.